# Equivalent of 'bug bounties' for information security in UX: 'dark pattern bounties'?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I asked a question regarding preventing RSI for mobile phone applications and the fact that game designers (many of them no doubt also UX designers) not doing anything to alleviate the amount of strain on the thumb and fingers but rather actually encouraging people to repeat clicking actions. It would be good to see some collective effort from the UX community to discourage this type of practice, since people don't seem to want to talk about ethic in design (judging from responses to questions I have asked previously on this topic, and the amount of tags on this topic in general).

Just wondering if it is worth setting up something like what companies offer penetration testers/white hat hackers with bug bounties but for the UX equivalent, which might be something like hidden dark patterns that use unethical design practices to intentionally harm users.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how that would work within the confines of a Question and Answer site, to be honest.

Just because something is of value to UX community that doesn't really mean it fits within every type of UX site. As a purely Question and Answer focused site that's all we're geared up to cater to.

OK, if you think someone has suggested something particularly negative from an ethics point of view then by all means downvote them and explain in comments why you have downvoted ([I myself have done this before](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/51324/am-i-providing-too-little-feedback#comment77365_51329)). Or alternatively you can award a bounty for a particularly good answer and comment there as to why you've done it. But I think beyond that would be verging beyond the scope of the Stack Exchange format.